# Obtaining Apple ID Login History

Tags: apple-id

I am trying to get a log in history of my Apple ID. I have gone to the data and privacy section of Apple and required the Apple ID data, but in there it only shows the most recent login, and not a list of logins from the last x days.

Is there a way to obtain a full history of log ins for my Apple ID?